# How to check what is active spring profile in Gradle task

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I need to run a specific task only when the build is being executed on Dev machine. Is there a way to get Spring active profile in gradle task ?

Comment: How are you configuring the active Spring profiles?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I configure them through application-{profile}.yml and while execution sometimes I rely on -d params sometimes on Env variables.

Comment: The concept of an active Spring profile only applies at runtime. You'll need to use another mechanism to tell your build what environment (dev, CI, etc) it is running in.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the other way round.

Set the environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` for defining the active profile and search for it in gradle:

```
def profile = System.getenv('SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE')

if (profile == "dev") {
    task myTask {
        println 'hello'
    }
}
```

If the environment variable is not set, nothing will happen.